# Input PHP Function Returned Values to SQL Database

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
public function post(){
    try{

        $con = connectDB();
        $sth = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts');
        $sth->execute();
        $posts = $sth->fetchAll();

        foreach($posts as $post){ ?>

            <div>
                <h2><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $post['content']; ?>
                </p>
                <h6><?php echo $post['category']; ?></h6>
            </div>

        <?php }

    }catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
}
```

And I want the return values of this function be stored in my database using my other function:

```
$page = new PageModel();
$post = new PostModel();

$page->addPage('Blog',$post->post());
```

But this one is not working. Can someone tell me what's wrong and if possible, suggest the most simple, possible way? Thanks!

Comment: your function is not returning anything ...

Answer (score 0):

Return the values to retrieve from other area

```
public function post(){
    try{

        $con = connectDB();
        $sth = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts');
        $sth->execute();
        $posts = $sth->fetchAll();

        foreach($posts as $post){ ?>

            <div>
                <h2><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $post['content']; ?>
                </p>
                <h6><?php echo $post['category']; ?></h6>
            </div>

        <?php }

    }catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}

return $posts;
}
```